# Should the code from book work?

Tags: java, tdd

Now I am reading Kent Beck's "Test Driven Development" and I have a problem with understanding of "Privacy" chapter. I use JUnit 4 and here is the code from chapter.

The class we will test:

```
public class Dollar {
    private int amount;

    Dollar(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Dollar times(int multiplier) {
        return new Dollar(amount * multiplier);
    }

    public boolean equals(Dollar d) {
        return amount == d.amount;
    }
}
```

The test (entirely copied from book):

```
public void testMultiplication() {
    Dollar five= new Dollar(5);
    assertEquals(new Dollar(10), five.times(2));
    assertEquals(new Dollar(15), five.times(3));
}
```

Reading a chapter i understand that this test should work. But it CAN NOT work because `times` method always returns new object so `assertEquals`s will always fail.

**My question is: should this test work?** Or it is given just as an example to translate it to another programming language?

Comment: This kind of mistake is exactly why the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation was created.

Answer (score 1):

Source : [Junit API](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4)

Source code of `assertEquals` says

```
/**
 * Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not
 * an AssertionFailedError is thrown with the given message.
 */
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (expected != null && expected.equals(actual)) {
        return;
    }
    failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}
```

When you call assertEquals, it calls the `.equals` on the `Dollar` class.

As  Bohemian mentioned, `@Override` -> of the `equals` method of `Object` class gives the power to check based on our custom implementation.

```
assertEquals(new Dollar(10), five.times(2));
```

`.equals` is calculated on amount, and it solves the purpose.

Comment: Just to clarify, the specific change that is needed is to implement `equals(Object)` and not just `equals(Dollar)`. @DevdattaK's suggestion of having your IDE generate `hashCode` and `equals` is a quick way to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this cannot work, because the objects will never be equivalent or exactly the same.

I guess the book was looking to give you a general concept, as opposed to an exact, perfectly correct answer, though I still think that examples in books should be usable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that assertEquals() has some issues calling the equals() method. While debugging, found that for some reason, instead of calling the overridden equals() method, junit libraries are going through reflection to find the correct class definitions to invoke the methods. It eventually ends up comparing the memory values of the objs.
Equals() however, as other contributors have pointed, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kevin Grant says, it should work.

Since you seem to just be learning JUnit, I only wanted to add, that you should always override the equals methods for your classes. If you don't, you only check if the reference variables point at the same memory-address by using assertEquals(). When using Eclipse you can easily do this by right-clicking anywhere in your code -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()...